# How do I get a line where the area on each side is equal?

Tags: python, numpy, integration

[image: An example of the areas I need].

[image]

I need to find a line that splits up the points so that the blue area is equal to the read area. I am doing this to a numpy array that has all of the x and y points in it. I have tried splitting it up and taking the areas of individual parts, but that is proving difficult for how many points I have.

My other idea was put this function on it's side, and integrate that way, and the areas would be equal when the integral is zero, but I can't find a function to let me choose the "x-axis" in that case. Anyone have any advice on how I might go about doing this?

[Edit] Original Picture (before the bad color job)

[image]

[Edit]

The x-values I am using can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/A3q6Zcad)
and the y-values to go along with those are [here](http://pastebin.com/cbZeyLi9)

Comment: What format is the data in? (Presumably it's not just a picture...)

Comment: it's a numpy array, a rather long, 1D array of floats that I generated from a Gaussian function.

Comment: Have you tried bisection search?

Comment: Could you show a reproducible example of the array so that we could give it a try? (Otherwise we'll have to generate our own data)

Comment: @DavidRobinson I have posted it on pastebin and more info on how to generate it.

Comment: If need be, I can also put the entirety of my code on GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my own problem by doing something fairly simple.

[image]

As can be seen in the image, I split the curve into its top, middle, and bottom sections (represented here by the different colors), then put a dividing line between them and did a Riemann Sum of sorts, moving the red line until the areas were equal.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** The code below isn't very good at dealing with generic functions, this other version of `area_difference` is a little more robust. It will still fail if the passed `x0` does not intersect the curve at least twice.

```
def area_difference(x0, x, y) :

    transitions = np.where(np.diff(x < x0))[0]

    x_ = x[transitions[0]:transitions[-1]]
    y_ = y[transitions[0]:transitions[-1]]

    return np.sum(np.diff(y_) * (x_[:-1] - x0))
```

---

You can get the area if you consider your curve defined as a parametric curve, the index of the array being the parameter. I think the following code is more or less straightforward given that basic idea. I haven't worried too much about getting off-by-one errors right, but any differences should be minor.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize

x = np.genfromtxt('x.txt')
y = np.genfromtxt('y.txt')

def area_difference(x0, x, y) :

    transitions = np.where(np.diff(x < x0))

    x_right = x[transitions[0][0]:transitions[0][1]]
    y_right = y[transitions[0][0]:transitions[0][1]]

    x_left = x[transitions[0][1]:transitions[0][2]]
    y_left = y[transitions[0][1]:transitions[0][2]]

    return (np.sum(np.diff(y_right) * (x_right[:-1] - x0)) +
            np.sum(np.diff(y_left) * (x_left[:-1] - x0)))

x0 = scipy.optimize.fsolve(area_difference, 3, args=(x, y))

plt.plot(x, y, 'b-')
plt.plot([x0, x0], [y.min(), y.max()], 'r-')
plt.show()

>>> x0
array([ 3.4174168])
```

[image]

Comment: You have helped me so much today, but I still have a problem with this. If I decrease the amount of time this function runs for (i.e. the top of this loop will be further to the left), I get IndexErrors that I cannot fix. Or if I use a different function, like a sine wave. Any suggestions there?

Comment: @NightHallow I have edited my answer with a more robust version of the `area_difference` function. The key is to have a starting guess for `fsolve` that intersects the curve at least twice.